# Bash redirect all output to file (beyond stderr and stdout)

Tags: bash

You can redirect stderr and stdout of a bash command to file using `foo > out.txt 2>&1`

But, consider: `ssh user@host > out.txt 2>&1`. In my experience, if a password is needed to connect, the password prompt will be displayed *to the screen* and not be sent to file.

For a more extreme example, `tmux > out.txt 2>&1` fails to redirect anything to file, except for a final `[exited]` message.

What's going on here, and is it possible to redirect all output?

Comment: Programs don't have to write to one of the standard streams; they can explicitly open `/dev/tty` and write to that.

Comment: Is there no way to redirect output sent directly to `/dev/tty`?

Comment: No, because it's a direct opening of a file, rather than writing to an inherited file descriptor.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using "| tee out.txt 2>&1" ?
Sorry, didn't understood your question... You need a terminal print and a file output?

Comment: The goal is to redirect all output sent to terminal to file